Data error of #REF data while sending email as Excel attachments (Email attachment is working fine)
I use following script to send multiple Google Sheets as attachment into one email, its working perfectly fine until a few days ago.
Here is the code:
function sendExcelAttachmentsInOneEmail() {
  var sheets = ['OH INV - B2B', 'OH INV - Acc', 'OH INV - B2C', 'B2B', 'ACC', 'B2C'];
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadSheetId = spreadSheet.getId();

  var urls = sheets.map(sheet => {
    var sheetId = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheet).getSheetId();
    // Used this alternative url since I'm getting the error below. This other url has less traffic issues during testing:
    // "This file might be unavailable right now due to heavy traffic. Try again."
    return `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=${spreadSheetId}&gid=${sheetId}&exportFormat=xlsx`;
  });

  var reportName = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('IMEIS').getRange(1, 14).getValue();

  var params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    // Add mute http exceptions to proceed
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var fileNames = ['OH INV - B2B.xlsx',
                   'OH INV - Acc.xlsx',
                   'OH INV - B2C.xlsx',
                   'B2B.xlsx',
                   'ACC.xlsx',
                   'B2C.xlsx'];

  var blobs = urls.map((url, index) => {
    // Added an interval due to heavy traffic error. Increase interval if needed.
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileNames[index]);
  });


  var message = {
    to: 'email@domain.com',
    cc: 'email@domain.com',
    subject: 'Combined - REPORTS - ' + reportName,
    body: "Hi Team,\n\nPlease find attached Reports.\n\nBest Regards!",
    attachments: blobs
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

Problem I am facing:
The data on these finale sheets (which i am sending as email attachment) is coming from different sheets using Google query() function as below:
=IF(Sheet11!H1<0,"-VE Stock Qty", query('INV SHEET'!A3:E,"SELECT * WHERE A IS NOT NULL",0))

In Google Sheet, The data always shows perfect and complete.
As soon I send email using above script, it sends as Excel attachment but the data / query function is replaced by #REF error as showing in below snip:

I tried many different scripts as well, all sending email as attachment but same error #REF in data file attachment.

What is included in the cell, and what is the description of the error message? (Use your mouse to point to the red triangle at the top right corner of the cell showing #REF!) P.D. The idea posted by Tanaike of converting sheet content to values before converting the spreadsheets to Excel files might be the simpler solution.

Error: Unresolved sheet name 'Sheet11'.

In your situation, as an approach, how about converting the formulas to the cell values? When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
function sendExcelAttachmentsInOneEmail() {
  var sheets = ['OH INV - B2B', 'OH INV - Acc', 'OH INV - B2C', 'B2B', 'ACC', 'B2C'];
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


  // --- I added the below script.
  spreadSheet = spreadSheet.copy("temp");
  spreadSheet.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  // ---


  var spreadSheetId = spreadSheet.getId();

  var urls = sheets.map(sheet => {
    var sheetId = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(sheet).getSheetId();
    // Used this alternative url since I'm getting the error below. This other url has less traffic issues during testing:
    // "This file might be unavailable right now due to heavy traffic. Try again."
    return `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=${spreadSheetId}&gid=${sheetId}&exportFormat=xlsx`;
  });

  var reportName = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('IMEIS').getRange(1, 14).getValue();

  var params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    // Add mute http exceptions to proceed
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var fileNames = ['OH INV - B2B.xlsx',
                   'OH INV - Acc.xlsx',
                   'OH INV - B2C.xlsx',
                   'B2B.xlsx',
                   'ACC.xlsx',
                   'B2C.xlsx'];

  var blobs = urls.map((url, index) => {
    // Added an interval due to heavy traffic error. Increase interval if needed.
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(fileNames[index]);
  });


  var message = {
    to: 'email@domain.com',
    cc: 'email@domain.com',
    subject: 'Combined - REPORTS - ' + reportName,
    body: "Hi Team,\n\nPlease find attached Reports.\n\nBest Regards!",
    attachments: blobs
  }

  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  

  // Added
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadSheetId).setTrashed(true);
}


By this modification, the formulas are converted as the cell values.

Reference:

copyTo(destination, options)


Thank you for helping, its still showing same error.
Below is the link to view picture:
link

@Atif Qayyum Thank you for replying. About Thank you for helping, its still showing same error. Below is the link to view picture: link, I think that in this case, it is required to test your situation using your sample Spreadsheet and your current script. Because, when I tested my proposed script using a sample Spreadsheet, no issue occurred. I apologize for this. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating still showing same error? By this, I would like to confirm it.
